# MSbuild typescript exclude folder

Tags: typescript, msbuild, visual-studio-2022

I have a VS2022 aspnet core 7.0-rc2 project with the Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild package version 4.8.4 (tried 4.9 beta no difference)

```
\project.csproj
\tsconfig.json
\clientapps\tsconfig.json
\clientapps\file99.tsx
\scripts\file1.ts
```

I have told VS to exclude the clientapps folder, and yet it the CompileTypeScriptWithTSConfig target still sees it and trys to compile it (and fails).

Excluding the ClientApps folder resulted in this being added to the csproj

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Remove="ClientApps\**" />
      <Content Remove="ClientApps\**" />
      <EmbeddedResource Remove="ClientApps\**" />
      <None Remove="ClientApps\**" />
      <TypeScriptCompile Remove="ClientApps\**" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

My root tsconfig file has

```json
  "include": [
    "scripts/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "clientapps/**/*.*"
  ]
```

I don't want msbuild to build anything in the ClientApps folder (react project using vite).
Any ideas on how to get msbuild/typescript to ignore a folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course minutes after I posted the question I resolved the problem - removing a jsconfig.json file from the project somehow solved it. I guess it was overriding what was in the tsconfig.

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider adding an answer and changing its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :) It will also help others to solve the similar issue.